# Magento 1.9 - Not getting recenlty uploaded product import files(CSV) on AWS server with CDN

Tags: magento-1.9, import, aws, cdn

When I upload CSV files from Magento backend under `System > Import/Export > Dataflow-Profiles > Upload File` tabs, files are uploaded successfully but **when check uploaded files under Run Profile tabs**, I did not get recently uploaded files in the dropdownlist. This is working fine on my local instance but not on live server which is hosted on Amazon cloud with CDN. But after reloading page it is showing in the dropdownlist. In subsequent request sometime it is showing or sometime not. Have checked requests on browser console and find that request is going to two different IPs and hence sometime uploaded files is showing in the dropdownlist or sometime not.

Now I am looking some way to sort out this issue so that uploaded files show every time even request is going other IP.

Please help me out to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

when using a CDN, the CDN’s cached copy of your site would need to be purged and updated after making changes.  Having your development team set up cache management in the .htaccess would give you options to somewhat control how quickly client’s will see updated versions of your site. Check out this link

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/41060/force-fresh-content-not-from-the-browser-cache

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8347595/htaccess-how-to-force-the-clients-browser-to-clear-the-cache

** btw i heard that it would take about 24hrs to bring updates on your website for AWS CDN

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But my issue is I have two servers and CSV file is uploaded on server itself. After successfully upload, CSV file is not showing if response coming from other server since recently uploaded file is not on other server. So I want to know how can I fix it.